# Forum Language Text

Tags: forum, language

With EE if you install more than language pack, once you are logged in as user it will use the text messages from your specific language preference. But does someone know how to force EE to use a specific language on a template or url and not by forcing someone to log in first?

For example, if you set up 2 forums. The default EE language is English but since each forum has its own URL, it makes no sense to display both in English.

If example.com/forum is using English but example.com/forum-fr should use French. In that example if a user that has set French on his control panel as language logs in, he will see the forum in French but the problem is that normal visitors that go to example.com/forum-fr will not. There must be a way to tell EE to load a different language without having to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Di you tried setting variable and/or using config..  in my index.php i use

```
$assign_to_config['deft_lang'] = 'french';
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['base_url'] = "https://your-domain.com/fr"; 
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(// This array must be associative 
    "lang" => "fr",
    "language" => "fr",
);
```

My whole is more complicated than that because i use htaccess to redirect to the right folders based on the browser language.... 
If you need my whole setup, let me know..

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I think that could be what I asked. Instruct EE to use a specific language folder for a specific URL instead of the default one.